# How can i use the NEW Firebase Analytics feature with a webapp?

Tags: web-applications, firebase, firebase-analytics

So at google i/o 2016, google announced firebase analytics feature, I currently only have a webapp on firebase, how i can use that feature? OR will I have to resort to something like Amplitude(Web and mobile Analytics)

Comment: Can we still not do it?

Comment: This is still not possible to do.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) supports iOS, Android and (since September 2019) [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web).

Comment: A little more than a year later, what is the recommended way to track a web app + an iOS app in the same property? My users can use both client apps (web and iOS), and eventually Android, and I want to track their sessions across client apps. I am starting from scratch and am not sure what to select when creating my Analytics property...

Comment: Two years later – also wondering why this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Crazy that given Google's mastery in web this is still not possible. The world marketing/user acquisition world is now centred around multi-channel user journeys (start on Instagram, go to web journey, go into app), and being able to track and optimize across these.

We use Amplitude to solve for this, which supports cross-platform metric journeys. Firebase Analytics badly needs the same.

Comment: Firebase analytics works in harmony with predictions and other features. It would be really great to have them all work for web as well. This is my feature request.

Comment: Three years later - Still it doesn't seem to be possible. Great :(

Comment: Finally they support firebase analytics on web.

Comment: Four years later it's now possible.

Answer (score 0):

This was just announced at I/O 2019 and is in beta:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-web

Comment: That's still only performance monitoring. Hope they have analytics on the near future roadmap as well. It's only taken two years and eleven months, come on Google!!!