# Is there any REST API to send data to firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase console gives good analytics data in one dashboard.

Is there any API by which I can push my analytics data from my own portal to Firebase analytics and see that analytics data in firebase analytics dashboard?

Comment: For APIs to add data to Firebase Analytics, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/. If you're asking whether there is a Web API, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330412/how-can-i-use-the-new-firebase-analytics-feature-with-a-webapp

Comment: Thanks for the response @Frank van Puffelen. I do not have a web app, I have android app and I wanted to know whether I can send data to firebase analytics from my own server or is there any REST api exposed to send data to Firebase analytics.

Comment: Hi @Praneeth, did you find a REST API for the above purpose? I also want a public API to get the firebase analytics via restapi.

Comment: Hi @GiridharaSPK No, I did not find any.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible at the moment. You need one of the mobile SDKs (iOS or Android) to compose the data.

Comment: So if I have a SPA app, how am I supposed to send Analytic data to Firebase? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible now?