# Accessing Firebase analytics from outside of Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I haven't found an answer searching on internet.

I want to be able to access firebase analytics from outside Firebase Console. I know how to Generate Analytics from my App, thats pretty easy.

But, I Want to create an App that reads analytics, because I want to create visual information of them.

Is it possible to do this? How can I achieve it?

Comment: There is no public API (yet) for accessing the aggregated analytics information. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330412/how-can-i-use-the-new-firebase-analytics-feature-with-a-webapp). But if your project is on a Blaze plan, you can export the raw events from Firebase Analytics to BigQuery. See [this help article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen why did you marked it as Duplicate? This is totally different, I know how to put data and events on Firebase Analytics, I just need to be able to read that data.

Comment: Good point, that is indeed not the duplicate I was looking for. This looks like a better matching dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095707/is-there-any-api-for-dashboard-analytics-data