# How to check which number of users(email/password auth) are currently logged in my apps from firebase console manually?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I need to see not total number of user. i only want them who are currently active (not signed out user) to my app through email and password. I want to see it from firebase console. help me please.

Comment: You can use real-time analytics to do that.

Comment: hi @GauravMall, it says the text from last 10 days,
"Your Analytics data will appear here soon
We're ready to start collecting your Analytics data. Integrate the SDK, and within 24 hours you'll see your first reports.
In the meantime, you can use DebugView to see events logged by your development devices in realtime."

Comment: Yes, you need to import the SDK into your app. What kind of app are you developing (Android, iOS, Web) ?

Comment: i am developing web app

Comment: check this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330412/how-can-i-use-the-new-firebase-analytics-feature-with-a-webapp

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Console doesn't show the number of users that are currently signed in to Firebase Authentication.

If you want to know how many users are actively using your app, you'll have to build something yourself.

Gaurav's comment about using an Analytics tool is a good hint. Even though Firebase's analytics SDK isn't available for the web, there are other analytics tools out there that would allow you to track the number of active users.

Another way is to write some information to a cloud database each time a user takes an action in your app. Then you can query that database to determine how many unique users recently took actions. That is actually pretty much what most analytics packages to. :)

A final option would be to use the Firebase Realtime Database's [presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample), which uses a more active approach to detect how many users are currently connected to the database.